# Postgres / Heroku - Handling data transfer from local to remote database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, flask

I am building a Flask app which I have deployed on Heroku. I recently added a Postgres database which I have been running locally and storing data in. I'm now ready to add the remote Postgres database to my Heroku site.

My question is what are the steps to transfer data from local to the remote Postgres database on Heroku?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to export your local database using pg_dump and import it on heroku using the PGBackups function.

A full explanation of the procces can be found on:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import